# The Adventures of a Chocolate Cookie

Tags: knowledge, story

> A chocolate cookie (we'll call her Ann) went to a store. She purchased a small mammal for free. The mammal was intended to replace another of Ann's possessions - no one really knew *what* it was, but it was very shiny. She had owned it from birth. Ironically, both the shiny thing and the small mammal constantly produced smaller versions of Ann. 
>   Later in the day, Ann began  to shake violently. Someone picked her up and began talking to her. Ann instantly felt better and stopped shaking. Later in the day, she started to shake again, but only *very* briefly - she had stopped for at least fifteen minutes before the person came over and checked on her.

What a day for Ann!

**Can you explain what *exactly* occurred during her day?**

---

*Please include an explanation for each relevant detail. The bare minimum is to identify what each object/person in the story is in reality.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think

> Ann Droid is a mobile phone, running the "Oreo" version of Google's mobile-device operating system.

*A chocolate cookie*

> Android *Oreo*.

*She purchased a small mammal*

> A *firefox*

*for free ... to replace another of Ann's possessions ... it was very shiny*

> *Chrome*.

*She had owned it from birth.*

> Chrome comes preinstalled on Android phones.

*... constantly produced smaller versions of Ann.*

> Cookies, though strictly the cookies are produced by websites rather than by the browser itself.

*Ann began to shake violently*

> An incoming phone call, probably. (Could be an alarm instead.)

*Someone picked her up and began talking to her.*

> Answered the phone. Or maybe it's possible to tell Android to cancel an alarm by voice.

*she started to shake again, but only very briefly*

> Maybe this one is just a notification. (Probably not an alarm, because those go on for longer.)

Comment: I'm beginning to think that you can read my mind with your speedy answers, and I can't even get mad about it: If you can't read my mind, then I have no reason to be mad. If you can read my mind, it probably isn't a good idea to be mad with you. :) Will accept this answer in a little bit.

Comment: No mind-reading abilities here, alas. Feel free to get mad if you find it helps, though.

Comment: Haha no worries, I'm not really mad - I am however, disappointed that you can't tell me what I'm thinking, 'cause I sure can't tell what I'm thinking. Nice solve, though! I guess I'll see if I can slide back up the difficulty scale for the next one.